# How to enable stripe.js on Android Chrome?

Tags: java, angular, spring, stripe-payments

I use stripe.js with PaymentIntent API to process card transactions on my Angular Spring Boot web app. I have been testing it fully deployed. On my pc, can create payments and the popup works to confirm card. But on the Android phone, it doesnt prompt me to confirm the card with 3DS. Also can't add a new card with stripe elements. No transaction happens. Is there a setting perhaps to enable stripe testing on the Android phone? Works 100% on my PC Chrome. Or maybe is there a reason stripe.js  wont load in the mobile browser?

Comment: No additional configuration is required to test Element integration with Payment Intent API. Stripe doesn't support Angular officially. If you use community library such as ngx-stripe, I'd recommend reaching out to their Support/GitHub to check whether additional setting is required.

Comment: But it works on computer with angular? I can't debug cause its mobile

Comment: I don't use that library just raw js.

Comment: I think the problem might be stripe.js isnt loading. Maybe the mobile browser it blocking it from loading.  Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out my requests to Stripe were happening from a local instance of my backend. The website was requesting from the REST API on my machine rather than the one running in Google Cloud. A quick change of URL from localhost to Google Cloud solved the issue.